# Replace na barra invertida "\" em java

Tags: java

Estou precisando tirar a barra invertida ("\") de uma string, ja pesquisei de diversos modos, porém nenhum deu certo.

Por favor, me ajudem, segue código.

```
f = new File(path,prefix + "_" + dataArq + "_" + pesquisa.replaceAll("\\", "") + ".txt");
System.out.println(pesquisa);
```

Estou tentando fazer o replace na string `pesquisa` para tirar a Barra Invertida que está vindo na geração do arquivo.

Comment: já tentou com \\\\ ?

Comment: Já tentou usar `replace` no lugar de `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ocorre que o primeiro parâmetro do método `replaceAll` é uma expressão regular. Assim sendo, há duas alternativas:

- Usar a expressão regular correta. Com `"\\\\"` no código-fonte, cada `\\` é uma sequência de escape para o caractere `\`, de forma que o conteúdo da string que o compilador irá ver será `\\`. Isso como expressão regular, é a sequência de escape para o caractere `\` sozinho.
- Não usar expressões regulares e usar o método `replace` ao invés de `replaceAll`.

Eis aqui um teste que usa ambas as abordagens:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String teste1 = "a\\b\\c\\d\\e";
        System.out.println(teste1);
        String teste2 = teste1.replace("\\", "");
        System.out.println(teste2);
        String teste3 = teste1.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        System.out.println(teste3);
    }
}
```

A saída dele é essa:

```
a\b\c\d\e
abcde
abcde
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/FjIcGW)

Ah, e lembre-se que strings são imutáveis, portanto se você fizer isso:

```
String pesquisa = "\\uma\\string\\cheia\\de\\barras\\invertidas\\";
f = new File(path,prefix + "_" + dataArq + "_" + pesquisa.replaceAll("\\\\", "") + ".txt");
System.out.println(pesquisa);
```

A string original cheia de barras invertidas é a que vai aparecer no `System.out.println`. Por outro lado, se você fizer isso:

```
String pesquisa = "\\uma\\string\\cheia\\de\\barras\\invertidas\\";
String pesquisa2 = pesquisa.replaceAll("\\\\", ""); // Ou .replace("\\", "");
f = new File(path,prefix + "_" + dataArq + "_" + pesquisa2 + ".txt");
System.out.println(pesquisa2); // É "pesquisa2"! Não é "pesquisa"!
```

Aí vai ser impresso o resultado sem as barras invertidas.

Comment: Creio que o replaceAll é a necessidade dele, pois as datas são as pastas e a pesquisa é o arquivo, mas já deixei o +1 porque já esta resolvido o problema de uma forma ou de outra

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Complementei a resposta. Acho que ele também não se atentou que está dando `System.out.println` na coisa errada.

Comment: Acho que esta 100% :)

Comment: Obrigado, deu tudo certo.