# Segunda barra invertida em meta-caracteres quando a expressão está entre aspas

Tags: javascript, regex

Quando se usa um *padrão* entre aspas é necessário acrescentar uma segunda barra invertida (`\`) nos meta-caracteres que possuem tal barra, como neste caso, por exemplo:

```
/\d+/ -> "\\d+"
```

Exemplos de código:

```js
var str = "Hello 123!";

// usando new RegExp()
var re = new RegExp("\\d+"); // entre aspas
var re2 = new RegExp(/\d+/); // sem aspas

// sem new RegExp()
var re3 = "\\d+";            // entre aspas
var re4 = /\d+/;             // sem aspas

console.log(str.match(re));
console.log(str.match(re2));
console.log(str.match(re3));
console.log(str.match(re4));
```

> Pelo que li **[nesta documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)**, o ponto (`.`) é o único
>   meta-caractere que não possui barra invertida, ao contrário de `\d`, `\w`, `\s` etc.

Qual seria a explicação lógica para a necessidade da segunda barra invertida em meta-caracteres (exceto `.`) quando o *padrão* é usado entre aspas?

Comment: Isso *basicamente* ocorre pois o *JS* usa a barra invertida para escapar os/alguns caracteres. `\b => `, `\f => `, `\u => (converte unicode)`, `\x => (converte hex)`, `\t => tab`, `\n => new line` etc. O *regex* estando entre aspas, o *JS* terá que escapar todos estes caracteres para só depois ter a expressão correta e processá-la.

Comment: Mais ou menos relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/316714/132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro de strings, a `\` é usada para codificar sequências de escape. Ou seja, é usada para codificar coisas que seriam difíceis de se colocar dentro da string de alguma outra forma. Para isso temos o `\n` que denota uma quebra-de-linha, o `\t` que denota um tab, as sequências `\u1234` para codificar caracteres unicode específicos e mais alguns outros casos. Todos esses casos são resolvidos em tempo de compilação (embora o javaScript seja interpretado, ele faz uma compilação *just-in-time* antes de começar a interpretar o código). Dessa forma, na string `"Bom\ndia"` o que o compilador vai montar será uma string com `Bom`, uma quebra-de-linha e `dia`.

No entanto, uma vez que o caractere `\` é usado para fazer o escape de outras sequências, então como seria para colocar o próprio caractere `\` na string? A resposta é com a sequência de escape `\\`. É por esse motivo que dentro de strings, quando você quiser escrever o caractere `\`, ele tem que ser dobrado.

Casos semelhantes acontecem com o `'` e com o `"`, que por serem terminadores de strings, podem ser representados como `\'` e `\"`, respectivamente quando estão dentro da string.

Até aqui não falamos nada de expressões regulares, mas a coisa complica porque as expressões regulares também usam o caractere `\` para fazer escape, e o utiliza para fazer sequências de escapes que em grande parte são bem diferentes das feitas com strings (embora para fazer o escape do próprio `\`, as expressões regulares também utilizam `\\`). Assim se você tiver uma string que aparece no código como `"\\d+"`, o compilador *just-in-time* do JavaScript vai montar na memória uma string com o conteúdo `\d+` e então o compilador de expressões regulares vai compilar essa expressão regular para um objeto que aceita um ou mais caracteres no intervalo `'0'` a `'9'`.

O ponto (`.`) é um caractere que não tem nada de especial nas strings, logo não precisa ser representado por qualquer sequência de escape. No entanto, nas expressões regulares, ele tem significado especial por poder representar qualquer caractere. Assim sendo, `new RegExp("abc.def")` vai se transformar numa expressão regular que reconhece 7 caracteres, sendo os três primeiros `abc`, os três últimos `def` e o do meio, qualquer coisa.

E como então representar o caractere `.` em uma expressão regular de forma literal? Nesse caso, deve-se usar a expressão regular `\.`. Só que se isso for codificado como string, você vai ter que usar `"\\."`.

O que acontece é que quando você representa expressões regulares com strings, há duas etapas de compilação envolvidas. Uma para montar a string em memória, aplicando as sequências de escape necessárias e uma segunda para converter a string em uma expressão regular, também aplicando as sequências de escape necessárias. Isso significa que nesse caso, o programador tem que ficar atento para ver o que que está sendo montado quando, o que pode ser bem confuso considerando que as duas etapas utilizam o mesmo caractere `\` para representar sequências de escape.

No entanto, quando você usa expressões regulares delimitadas por `/`, tal como em `/\d+/` ou em `/\./`, neste caso você não está construindo uma string, e sim instruindo o compilador a construir a expressão regular diretamente sem o passo intermediário de representá-la como string. Por isso que nesse caso o `\d` e o `\.` não devem ser representados como `\\d` ou `\\.`.

Ah, e é por causa disso que `new RegExp("\\\\")` é a expressão regular que é usada para reconhecer uma única `\` singular. A string que será montada será `\\`, que interpretando como expressão regular, torna-se apenas `\`.

Comment:  Estava lendo aqui uma doc de regex em Phyton que fala justamente isso, mas eu estava tendo dificuldade em entender, ainda mais em inglês :/... a sua resposta esclareceu tudo. Ficou claro que nem água e de fácil leitura. ObG!